# Iterative binary tree insert function in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, insert, iteration, binary-tree

I'm making a comparison between recursive and iterative algorithms, and I am currently trying to create an iterative "insert()" method to place things into my binary tree. (I've made my own tree structure). The code is as follows.

```
public void insert(Object objectToInsert) {
    root = insert(objectToInsert, root);
}

private Node insert(Object objectToInsert, Node tree) {
    Node nodeToInsert = new Node(objectToInsert);
    boolean inserting = true;
    while (inserting) {
        if (tree == null) {
            tree = nodeToInsert;
            inserting = false;
            treeSize++;
        } else {
            if (nodeToInsert.getUniqueID() < tree.getUniqueID()) {
                tree = tree.getLeft();
            } else {
                tree = tree.getRight();
            }
        }
    } // end while loop
    return tree;
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something really simple here?
Thank you!

Heads up:
Object() is a class I made - not Java's native class.

Comment: Yes, you ***are*** missing something here. Try to print your tree and see that it'll always be empty...

Comment: I did that, it always just overwrites the root node... How should I fix this?

Comment: You're saving too late - when your node is `null` there's nothing that'll connect the current node to the tree. You should save when the node is *not* null, but when its left/right-child are null and the current inserted node should become its left/right-child. On that case you'll do, for example: `if (tree != null && tree.getLeft() == null && nodeToInsert.getUniqueID() < tree.getUniqueID()) tree.setLeft(nodeToInsert);`